# Flash vs Silverlight on Localhost /local file permission to access remote webservice

Tags: silverlight, flash

In Flash user can give permission to localhost and even local html file to access remote webservice.

I fail to see the same thing for Silverlight which is a nightmare for testing on local pc.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what you are not able to accomplish?

I can access local and remote webservices from a local Silverlight app easily as long as a [cross domain policy file](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx) is correctly configured.

Comment: from a simple file:///test.html which embeds silverlight also ?

Comment: Yes, because Silverlight checks whether or not the webservice is hosted on the same server by its URL. Read the article I linked to.